# Delete cookies in Webdriver

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver

There is a `.delete_all_visible_cookies` method in Selenium. I was surprised to discover that `.delete_all_cookies` in Webdriver is a part of private API thus is not accessible through @driver instance.

It is a problem for IE since it does not start a clean browser on a new test run as FF.

Answer (score 4):

From what I know you have to options:

- When creating the IE instance use capabilities argument:

  DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
  caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.ForSeleniumServer.ENSURING_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
  WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);
- Once initialized, you can use:

  driver.manage().deleteAllCookies()

Comment: Seems like a solution. Looking for a Ruby equivalent of it.

Comment: According to this you can do the equivalent with capabilities for Ruby-->  http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver.html

Comment: Still I am not able to find a solution. The capabilities available are those here http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Remote/Capabilities.html . where there is no clean_session or clear_cookies or similar displayed. I am getting lost... I am sure that many developers face this problem. How do you tackle it?

Comment: ENSURING_CLEAN_SESSION clears cache, it is not written anywhere that it clear cookies.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I was not able to solve this issue by means of Webdriver. Finally, what I do is simply delete the cookies from the command line before running the tests. The line is

```
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This part of code create an option object and sets Clean Session Property to true and passes it to Explorer driver while creating a driver instance. Works for me.

```
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.EnsureCleanSession = true;
return new InternetExplorerDriver(Config.IEDriverPath, options);
```

Comment: In general, you should include the explanation of your code in the answer itself, rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

IN IEDRIVER 2.53.1 
The IE can delete the cache by using

```
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.ENABLE_ELEMENT_CACHE_CLEANUP, true);
```