# Delete cookies in Selenium Webdriver using IE11

Tags: java, internet-explorer, cookies, selenium, windows-7

I'm trying to delete all cookies before running a Selenium test.

According to [How to clear browser cache automatically in Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16461472/how-to-clear-browser-cache-automatically-in-selenium-webdriver) and 
[Delete cookies in Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413966/delete-cookies-in-webdriver) my code is:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255");
p.waitFor();

DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.ForSeleniumServer.ENSURING_CLEAN_SESSION,true);
WebDriver webDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);
webDriver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

testBrowser = new TestBrowser(webDriver, "http://localhost");
testBrowser.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

However, the cookies are not deleted.

My environment is: Windows 7, 64bit, IE11.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution for your problem is to try deleting the cookies by name. For example, instead of:

```
webDriver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

Use:

```
webDriver.manage().deleteCookieNamed("JSESSIONID");
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem and none of the provided methods for deleting cookies worked.

A possible solution is that you configure your browser to launch with a clean session like this:

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);

I found the solution here: http://www.frontendtest.org/blog/ie-cache-selenium/

I hope that will help. At least, it worked for me :)